# Someone upvoting my old answers at a rate of 2-3 per day

Tags: discussion, votes

Think I am experiencing a weird stalk-upvoting behaviour this week. Every day I see 2-3 of my old answers being upvoted. And the upvoting started from the lowest-score answers (that had 0 score) and seems to be moving upwards.

I am not sure if the system is reverting or will revert the score from those votes. And obviously I am not upset about it. But my question is - what am I supposed to be doing in this case? Should I report this somewhere?

Whoever is doing it seems to be familiar with the SO system and visit this site every day.

Comment: 2-3 shouldn't be reverted. You needn't do anything about the fact that someone is upvoting your posts.

Comment: @gung thank you for response. I will not think about it more in this case. But it's definitely not organic. I get 2-3 every day for a week now and each day the upvotes start from the place they left-off the day before (when ordering the answers by score).